# How I build Dart Regexp Properly?

Tags: dart

Goal of this expression is *separate* mathematic calculations into operators, symbols, numbers and brackets.

For example:

`Input string: 1+3-6*(12-3+4/5)`

`Output list: 1, +, 3, -, 6, *, (12-3+4/5)`

So I built [this expression.](https://regexr.com/6l7sr)

It is working on the web page, but in the Dart code this happens:

```
final calculationExpression = RegExp(
  r"/(\(([a-zA-Z0-9-+/*]+)\))|([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|([+/*-]{1})/g",
  unicode: true,
  multiLine: true,
);

...

List<String> operators = calculationsString.split(calculationExpression); /// Output: ["", "+", "-", ...]
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The syntax `/pattern/g` is used to create regular expression *literals* in JavaScript (and `sed` and some other languages), just as quotes are used to create string literals.  Dart doesn't have regular expression literals; you instead must invoke the `RegExp` constructor directly.  Combining a regular expression literal syntax with an explicitly constructed `RegExp` object makes no sense.  When you do `RegExp(r'/pattern1|pattern2|pattern3/g')`, you're actually matching against `/pattern1` (`pattern1` prefixed with a literal `/` character) or `pattern2` or `pattern3/g` (`pattern3` followed by a literal string `/g`).
2. [`String.split`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/String/split.html) does not split the input string such that each element of the result matches the pattern.  It treats all matches of the pattern as *separators*.  Consequently, the resulting list will not have any elements that match the pattern, which is the opposite of what you want.  You instead want to find *all* matches of the pattern in the string.  You instead can use [`RegExp.allMatches`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/RegExp/allMatches.html) *if* you additionally verify that the input string contains *only* matches from the regular expression.

Putting it all together:

```dart
void main() {
  final calculationExpression = RegExp(
    r"(\(([a-zA-Z0-9-+/*]+)\))|([a-zA-Z0-9]+)|([+/*-]{1})",
    unicode: true,
    multiLine: true,
  );

  var calculationsString = '1+3-6*(12-3+4/5)';

  // Prints: [1, +, 3, -, 6, *, (12-3+4/5)]
  print(calculationsString.tokenizeFrom(calculationExpression).toList());
}

extension on String {
  Iterable<String> tokenizeFrom(RegExp regExp) sync* {
    void failIf(bool condition) {
      if (condition) {
        throw FormatException(
          '$this contains characters that do not match $regExp',
        );
      }
    }

    var matches = regExp.allMatches(this);
    var lastEnd = 0;
    for (var match in matches) {
      // Verify that there aren't unmatched characters.
      failIf(match.start != lastEnd);
      lastEnd = match.end;

      yield match.group(0)!;
    }

    failIf(lastEnd != length);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You put the JavaScript regexp literal slashes and flags inside the Dart string.

If you remove the leading `/` and trailing `/g`, you get the RegExp you intended to.
The `multiLine` and `unicode` flags are unnecessary (your regexp doesn't use any feature affected by those)

The Dart `split` function does not emit capture groups, so you probably want to look at getting the matches, not removing them, which is what `split` does.

All in all, try:

```dart
final calculationExpression = RegExp(
    r"\([a-zA-Z\d\-+/*]+\)|[a-zA-Z\d]+|[+/*\-]");
List<String> tokes = 
    calculationExpression.allMatches(calculationsString).toList();
```